# Construction "if then else" in alert rules alertmanager(prometheus)

Tags: monitoring, notifications, prometheus-exporter

Right now I have two rules for "Warning" and "Critical" alerts. Is it possible to combine them somehow, so as not to produce entities?

```
  - alert: Proxysql latency check
    expr: metric1 > 1
    for: 30s
    labels:
      severity: warning
      instance: "{{ $labels.node_name }}"
      label: name-channel
    annotations:
      summary: "Info"

  - alert: Proxysql latency check
    expr: metric1 > 5
    for: 30s
    labels:
      severity: critical
      instance: "{{ $labels.node_name }}"
      label: name-channel
    annotations:
      summary: "Info"
```

An example of how I present it:

```
      - alert: Proxysql latency check
    expr: if metric1 > 1 then "Warning" else metric > 5 "Critical" 
    for: 30s
    labels:
      severity: warning | critical
      instance: "{{ $labels.node_name }}"
      label: name-channel
    annotations:
      summary: "Info"
```